# AppleScripts won't let docker run on my mac

Tags: docker, macos, applescript

I foolishly listened to ChatGPT and ran an applescipt command without completely knowing what it would do. The command was `osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"'` which I thought would simple force quit the app.

However, now, nothing I do can get the docker engine to boot up. `Docker` is still a recognized command in the terminal, but any command like `docker build .` can't connect to the docker daemon, because it isn't running.

I open docker desktop, it starts to initialize, and then suddenly interrupts and starts to shut down!

I restarted my computer, and even uninstalled Docker Desktop and reinstalled it. But on reinstall `osascipt` demanded my fingerprint/password becfore it would let me complete the install, and then immediately closed the app.

I had thought that that apple script command would simply close the app. But apparently I issued a persisting command that will immediately close the docker engine anytime I try to turn it on...

How do I undo this? I can't find anything...

I wrote this command `osascript -e 'tell app "Docker" to activate'` hoping that it would sort of cancel out the first, but no luck. It just tries to open Docker Desktop which is then interrupted and immediately closed...I'm very stuck.

Comment: You can try `open -a docker`.

Comment: "I foolishly listened to ChatGPT" LOL! I fail to understand why anyone would consult ChatGPT for programming advice. It's a LLM (large language model). It scrapes text from sites like StackOverflow and predicts which sequence of words is most probable. It doesn't understand what it is reading or writing and will happily emit garbage if its LLM says that garbage maximizes its fitness model.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3941 Does any of these workarounds work for you?

Comment: Try to find relevant log files to see if they give any clues.

Comment: You must've done something else: `osascript -e` simply runs the given command (`quit app "Docker"`, in this case) as a one-line script command. There's nothing wrong whatsoever with what you entered, assuming it was that one single line, run in Terminal, say. However, if you created a text script and set it up with `launchd` for example, it might be running every time you start Docker. We'll need more information on how you entered/setup this script. (And some advice: don't mention *chatGPT* here - it's a 4-letter word to some people)